# KDevelop - C++: How to start tracing a simple main.cpp?

Tags: c++, kdevelop, debug-mode

I cannot seem to run a simple hello world application in debug mode. When I press the Debug button, the application executes and ends normally, even though I have put a breakpoint on the line that "hello world" is printed. I have also gone through this menu: "Run > Configure Launches..." and selected the Executable file. Is there any other thing I have to do to get into debugging mode? The version of KDevelop is 4.7.4 and OS: Linux Mint

I have also noticed that all tracing commands in Run menu are disabled (Step Over, Step Into, ...)

Comment: We can assume you read http://userbase.kde.org/KDevelop4/Manual/Debugging_programs , right?

Answer (score 1):

Build your application with debug symbols.

For example if you use cmake add `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` to your cmake call. (Or choose it in KDevelop if you create the build folder there)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the problem I had. I had put the name of the exe I was trying to debug in the `debugger executable` field of the `debug` page of my `launch configuration`. This field is however for the debugger program itself, e.g. `/usr/bin/gdb`.